# Necessary and sufficient conditions for the embeddability of a semigroup in a group

Tags: group-theory, math-history, semigroups, translation-request

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup#Embeddability_in_groups),

> The first set of necessary and sufficient conditions for the embeddability of a semigroup in a group were given in (Malcev 1939).[5] Though theoretically important, the conditions are countably infinite in number and no finite subset will suffice, as shown in (Malcev 1940).[6]

Although very important, Malcev's two papers share a fundamental flaw; they're both written in Russian, and alas, I do not speak Russian.

**Question 1.** What was Malcev's countably infinite set of (necessary and sufficient) conditions?

**Question 2.** And what other characterizations have been discovered since 1940?

Comment: It's a little weird to call it a "flaw" to be written in a foreign language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the Malcev's theory in 2nd vol. of *Algebraic theory of semigroups* by Clifford and Preston. You will also find there the more late results of Lambeck.

**Addendum:**

N. Bouleau,  Classes de semigroupes immersible dans groupes, *Semigroup Forum*,**6**(1973), N.2, pp.100-112.

S.I. Adyan, Defining relations and algorithmic problems for groups and semigroups. 
*Proc. Steklov Inst. Math.* **85**(1966), 152 p.; translation from *Tr. Mat. Inst. Steklov* **85**(1966), 123 p.

Comment: @ user18921: I added the answer.